# How to multiply each row in matrix by its scalar in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

For instance I have a matrix and a vector of scalars

```py
A = np.array([
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9]
])

B = np.array([1, 2, 3])
```

The output that I want to get is like this, basically I want to multiply each row by scalar that have same index

```py
 1   2   3
 8  10  12
21  24  27
```

Comment: Transpose `B`, then just use `*`.  You'll need to make it 2D first.

Comment: @Him, B.T * A didn't work.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem, Yes sir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use broadcasting: `A * B[:, None]`:

```py
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 8, 10, 12],
       [21, 24, 27]])
```